# Do upvotes from new users affect your reputation

Tags: discussion

Do you gain reputation for helping new users(**below the rep needed for up votes to be seen**)?

I'm asking because i remember there was a threshold of rep you needed for reps to 'count'.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you gain reputation for helping new users(**below the rep needed for up votes to be seen**)?

No, you don't, unless a privileged user gives your post an upvote.
Unless new users (users without upvoting privilege) really gain that privilege their upvotes will have no effect on your posts and your reputation.
They're just notified that their votes have been recorded by the system (as anonymous feedback).

Even not if those users will gain that privilege later on.

Comment: [(whatever that actually means)](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/861487)

Comment: For completeness, askers of any reputation level may accept answers, an action that comes with a +15 rep reward.

Comment: "votes have been recorded by the system " is a euphemism for "You need 15 reputation to upvote."

Comment: @CommunityNoDiamond. See _@rene_'s link. These actually are recorded. No real impact though.

Comment: It is still a euphemism.

Comment: @community Well, the 1st rule is: ***Be nice!*** No matter how _greasy_ that might look realizing the final conclusion. This is my today's [t-shirt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3NY7.jpg):

Comment: There actually is [one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits) on the network where anonymous votes can be seen next to the question, for some specific questions. So they might have minimal influence in that they might count towards getting questions on that list, and can be seen without using SEDE.